# For inside for - how to do inner for parallel without spending time on creating threads

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp

I'm new in OpenMP and
I'm facing situation like this:

```
int someArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

//outer loop
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

    //inner loop 
    for(int j = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        //calculaations in someArray (every cell can be calculated separately)
    }

    //some code that needs to be run by only one thread - for example sorting someArray
}
```

I want to make inner loop parallel, but idea that I tried (code below) is not effective (single thread can do things faster than multiple threads). I think that creating multiple threads over and over waists a lot of time here.

My bad solution:

```
int someArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

//outer loop
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(THREADS_NUMBER) shared(someArray)
    {
        //inner loop
        #pragma omp for
        for(int j = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
            //calculaations in someArray (every cell can be calculated separately)
        }
    }

    //some code that needs to be run by only one thread - for example sorting someArray
}
```

Do you have any idea how to optimise this task?

Answer (score 0):

When you have double for loops, you almost always want to parallize the outer loop. In your case:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

    for(int j = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        //calculations in someArray (every cell can be calculated separately)
    }

    //some code that needs to be run by only one thread - for example sorting someArray
}
```

If you have 4 CPUs available, this will split the 100 iterations into 25 across the 4 CPUs. This is much more efficient than your code, which ends up, for each of the 100 iteration, splitting ARRAY_SIZE across the CPUs (you thus has 100x the overhead).

Comment: But the outer loop needs to be in one thread, because there is array sorting in the end of a cycle (which is schared resource). The ARRAY_SIZE can be around 66 milions. So what i want is to parallize only inner loop (where separate cells are recalculated independently).

Comment: I also tried to put barrier and then fake master
    -> if(0 = thread_number)
but its illegal statement.

Comment: I would need more context to be able to help - what are you trying to achieve? Can you elaborate your sample so that it shows a performance issue?